# Robot Framework Keyword with Python: Error with unmatched string or IP. How to fix this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to write a keyword for Robot Framework as @Brayan Oakley suggesed in Question :

> [How to write python function to test the matched strings (to use for Robot framework keyword)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694437/how-to-write-python-function-to-test-the-matched-strings-to-use-for-robot-frame/32694506#32694506)

My Python file:

```
import os,re

def check_IP():
    cmd = ' netstat -ano '
    output = os.popen(cmd).read()
    match1 = re.findall('.* (1.1.1.1).*',output)
    mat1 = ['1.1.1.1']
    if match1 == mat1:
        print "IP addr found"
    if match1 != mat1:
        raise Exception('No matching IP...')

check_IP()
```

I am trying to match a IP address in "netstat -ano" command. If its matches, I am getting "IP addr found" message as expected.

But if IP address is not found I am getting exception as expected, but with below error messages.

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>python check.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 13, in <module>
    check_IP()
  File "check.py", line 11, in check_IP
    raise Exception('No matching IP...')
Exception: No matching IP...

C:\Users\test\Desktop>
```

Any clue to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is doing precisely what you told it to do. You are running the code outside of the context of robot, and this is how python treats exceptions.

If you don't want to see the stack trace, catch the exception and print whatever message you want.

```
    try:
        check_IP()
    except Exception as e
        print str(e)
```

Of course, you'll want to remove all that code if you use `check_IP` as a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following Robot File:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Test Stability Tests
Library        Network.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test: Test Robot File
    Check Network Status
```

Use the following Python File

```
import os, re
def check_network_status():
    cmd = ' netstat -ano '
    output = os.popen(cmd).read()
    match1 = re.findall('.* (1.1.1.1).*',output)
    mat1 = ['1.1.1.1']
    if match1 == mat1:
        print("IP Address found")
    elif match1 != mat1:
        raise AssertionError("IP Address not Found")
```

Note: Do not call the function in the Python file. 
Just create classes and function inside python file(if you want to in future). 
They would automatically be called off at the run time.